# Opening Files In Protected ZIP Archive

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, zip

(Visual Studio Ent. 2015 // Visual Basic)

I'm working on a browser project which only opens html files in a folder that is inside the same directory of .exe file. As you can imagine those html files are really easy to reach. I want to make them harder or impossible to reach without the browser application. Creating these html files directly in the application is not a solution because in the future browser will stay the same but html files will be changed.

So the thing that i want to know is it possible to zip the html files (of course with the .js and image files) and make my browser control open them from zip archive. Then i want to protect the zip with password so users cannot reach the html files without the browser. By the way i don't mind if the files should be extracted to Temp folder as long as a standart user cannot reach them easily it's fine.

I'll add a screenshot to make it more clear to understand. Basically what i'm looking for is some code like below one (below code is just a fantasy of course :));

```
Dim filePath As String = IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath)

Browser1.Url = ("filePath & "\DATA.zip\index.html", Password:test")
```

[Screenshot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzduI.png)

Comment: you can try http://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/ sharpziplib. it can everything you  asked for with lot of examples.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was afraid to use libaries but when you mentioned i gave it a try. Not sharpziplib but dotnetzip ionic libary did the job so easily. Have a nice day.